# Button doesn't update in Ajax on Users Index page - Rails Tutorial 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, railstutorial.org

TLDR: Trying to add a follow/unfollow button to the Users#Index action but when clicking on the button nothing happens.

I have followed Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial app and now that it's complete I want to add extra functionality for the Follow/Unfollow button. Currently, you can only follow/unfollow a user after visiting their profile page thru the Users Show action. I've attempted to expand this functionality to the Index page of the Users controller so that instead of having to visit each user's profile page in order to follow/unfollow them, a follow button will also appear next to their name in the Index view.

The code that works initially for the follow/unfollow button on the Users Show action:

users_controller.rb

### https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9602598

show.htlm.erb for users view

### https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9602616

_follow_form.htlm.erb partial for users view

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

_follow.html.erb partial for users view

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

_unfollow.html.erb partial for users view

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

---

create.js.erb inside of my relationships view

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

destroy.js.erb inside of my relationships view

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

index.html.erb inside of the users view

```
  <%= render @users %>
```

---

_user.html.erb partial inside of users view

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
```

I've tried a few different approaches that so far have been fruitless

First I tried simply rendering the follow_form partial inside of the _user partial just like it's done for the User Show view

_user.html.erb partial inside of users view

```
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
```

this resulted in the following error: NoMethodError in Users#index "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" and it hilights the following line of code inside of the follow_form partial

```
<% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
```

---

After mucking around with the variables and the controller for a few hours I finally managed to get the buttons to show properly on the index page with the following code inside of the _user.html.erb partial

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
      <%= form_for(@current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @users),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @users),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

This code however, only shows the correct follow/unfollow buttons for each user but when you click a button nothing happens. I also attempted to edit the JS files with the following code

create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#user").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#user").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

This didn't have any effect.

The more I tinker with different parts of the code the more it's confusing me. Here is my relationships controller for good measure.

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I know it's alot but if anyone can help shed some light on my situation I would be very grateful. This is my first venture outside of tutorials and I figured it would be a good idea to try and add features to an already working project instead of start something from scratch.

Comment: The question goes in the category of TLDR. Could you please make it precise and compact.

Comment: Definitely. I added a tldr to the top of the post. I was really just trying to be thorough in documenting all my steps in attempting to solve the problem. I guess I don't really know how to make it more compact without feeling like I'm leaving out something that may be part of the problemor help with coming up with a solution.

Comment: Your intention is correct BUT In order to get answers to your question I think being precise would help. As people tend to skip the TLDR questions because its a TLDR.

Comment: Add only relevant information in the question. You could share extra information when someone asks or upload the files on gist and share the link in the question.

Comment: Kirti, thanks for the info! I wish i had known about Gist before i wrote this post, would have been wayyyyy better. I'm gonna take the question down for now and adjust it. I'll admit tho that I kinda feel like I don't know what informaton is pertinent to solving my problem and what isn't but i think gradually adding more info as I'm asked could be a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following code in `_user.html.erb` partial:

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

I made couple of changes to the code in `form_for` method call in 2 places:

`@current_user` should be `current_user`.

Secondly, `followed_id: @users` should be `followed_id: user.id`

Comment: Thanks so much for the input Kirti, I swear I tried 50 different combinations with user, @user, users, all sorts of stuff and I though i had tried this combo before as well but i was totally wrong. This works close to 100%!! It looks like my final issue is with AJAX which i pretty much have no clue of what to do with. If i click the button on the index page, it doesn't visually change the button, but if i refresh the page then it will show the updated follow/unfollow status

Comment: No Problem.:) I am not much of an expert in Ajax. You could just post a new question with the index page details + ajax code. Some ajax expert would surely guide you in right direction.

Comment: actually ("#follow_form") is the name of the div maybe and so if i add an id to the div for the index page maybe that will work. ill give it a shot now

Comment: yup that was it. However tagging a div inside of the user partial as #user is currently only visually affecting the first user on the list so i've gotta come up with a wait to uniquely identify the div for each record i guess and let the javascript know.. Idk, im gonna fool around with it and if I can't manage to figure it out then I'll consider opening a new question. Thanks again Kirti

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody was on this question and was still looking for the correct Ajax code. This works with the existing controller and nothing else will have to be changed.

create.js.erb

```
    var indexed_form = "follow_form_<%=@user.id%>"
    if ( document.getElementById(indexed_form) ){
        var jquery_indexed_form = "#" + indexed_form
        $(jquery_indexed_form).html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
    } 
    else {
        $("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
        $("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
    }
```

destory.js.erb

```
    var indexed_form = "follow_form_<%=@user.id%>"
    if ( document.getElementById(indexed_form) ){
        var jquery_indexed_form = "#" + indexed_form
        $(jquery_indexed_form).html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>");
    }
    else {
        $("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>");
        $("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
    }
```

_user.html.erb

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
          <% unless current_user?(user) %>
            <% form_id = user.id.to_s %>

              <div id="follow_form_<%= form_id %>">
                <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
                    <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
                  html: { method: :delete },
                  remote: true) do |f| %>                       
              <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
            <% end %>

        <% else %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
              <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>              
              <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>

        <% end %>

      </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

This is my first post. Yay! Hope it helps someone!

Comment: This completely breaks the layout of the user list at http://localhost:3000/users